# Django tag within URL tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to use dynamic images based on a a pk of the page. 
To be clearer I have a survey app, using one question per page .. which mean that the user is presented a question he answers and is redirected to the next question. Each question has a different id and I would like to attach to each question an image. 
Right now I have a static image lik that :

```
<div class="col-5">
   <img src="{% static 'images/RightSpeech.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

but I would like to make it dynamic.. I tried something like that with no success:

```
<div class="col-5">
    <img src="{% static 'images/image{{question.pk}}.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

any idea ?

[image]

Comment: if each question had a url ~> you can get the id/pk in url and sent data (image) to display.
if you did it within page (without change the page's url), you can use js file with ajax and then reload the page content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` tag doesn't really do anything more than adding the value of STATIC_URL to whatever you pass it. Instead of messing about with all these tags, you could just do this manually:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/images/image{{question.pk}}.jpg"
```

If for some reason the static context processor isn't activated, you can use the `{% get_static_prefix %}` tag in exactly the same way:

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}/images/image{{question.pk}}.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
{% static 'images/image'|add:question.id|add:'.jpg' %}
```

in order to get concatenate the question PK to the image name. This just makes use of the concatenation filter `|add:`.

**EDIT 1**

If the above does not work, you can try to use the `{% with %}` tag, so in your case:

```
{% with "images/image"|add:question.id|add:".jpg" as customUrl %}
    {% static customUrl %}
{% endwith %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: in my inspect it is what I get /static/images/question%7B%7Bquestion.id%7D%7D.jpg so I do not think it is a question of extracting the ID

Comment: nop it  is now empty; my code is : {% static 'images/question'|add:survey.id|add:'.jpg' %} and in the inspect src="/static/.jpg"

Comment: @Ben2pop I have made an edit, please check that, it should be working

Comment: i edited my post with a picture .. have a look please

Comment: well the code is the same, so have you tried using the `{%with%}` tag? @Ben2pop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161285/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-n-ivanov).